# Pyspark : When I print accumulator , its giving zero value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Below is a sample pyspark code snippet where I am trying to check (as a sanity check), how many orders are processed after "filter" Transformation. 
So I am trying to define an accumulator and use it as counter for getting "no.of orders processed".

```
    orders=inputpath + "/orders" # Accepting and creating  the "full input path" for input file
    counter=sc.accumulator(0) #defining accumulator

    def OrderTuples(order): #defining a function to incorporate "counter increment" for every records filtered out from filter transformation to the map transformation
        counter.add(1) 
        return (int(order.split(",")[0]),1)

     ordersFiltered = sc.textFile(orders). \
        filter(lambda order : month in order.split(",")[1]). \
        map(lambda order : OrderTuples(order)) # Calling the  function here
    print(f"NO OF ORDERS PROCESSED:{counter}") # printing the accumulator final value here
```

But as final output, I am still getting zero value. Where I am going wrong. I am using accumulator for the first time.
sc.textFile(orders) is having 2 partitions by default and I am using --num-executors 2(13 node cluster)
Appreciating helping hands here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ordersFiltered` needs an action performed (like collect) before the filter lambda is actually evaluated